# What should be done when two users ask the same question, but for different Drupal versions?

Tags: discussion, questions

- [How do I create custom tokens?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6765/how-do-i-create-custom-tokens)
- [How to programmatically create a custom token in a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/programmatically-create-a-token)

Both the questions are about implementing tokens, but the first question is about Drupal 7, and the second one is about Drupal 6. The answers for the questions are completely different, as the hooks implemented by the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module are different from the hooks used by Drupal 7 for token generation; porting a Drupal 6 module implementing tokens to Drupal 7 requires to write new code.

What should be done, in this case?

- The second question is edited to remove the Drupal version tag, and an answer is added to explain how to implement tokens in Drupal 7.
- Both the questions are kept.

Does the answer change, if the differences between Drupal versions that are relevant for the question are minimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the techniques are totally different for [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) and [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6), then each question should have a version tag and remain in place.

We had also talked about having one question which contains two answers:

1. here's how to do it in 6
2. here's how to do it in 7

Really I could go either way on this, so long as people searching for this information can *find* it, that is the goal.

Comment: In the case of the questions I reported, as one of the question has been closed as duplicate of the other one, I edited the still open question to remove the version tag, and added an answer for Drupal 7. In this case, the techniques are totally different, but would having two questions for different Drupal versions make sense, when the differences are minimal?

Comment: If the differences are minimal then there should only be 1 Question with 1 answer.  Such as:  Drupal 6: X,  Drupal: 7, change line A & B to X & Y.   For the questions that state how to do X in Drupal 6, I try to answer their version first, then show the difference in Drupal 7 (or vice-versa).   Sometimes I edit the question to be more general to include both versions.